# BGE - move (absolute) camera to static target

Tags: game-engine

I want to move a camera to a specific target coordinate or object. 
I tried the actuator "Motion" but i get just relative movements and no movement to a static object.

How can i realize this?

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1):

With your camera create an animation action with location keys.

Example:

- frame 1 - Position A
- frame 2 - Position B
- frame 3 - Position C

## Option A)

When you want to set position A you play the action from frame 1 to frame 1.
When you want to set position B you play the action from frame 2 to frame 2.
When you want to set position C you play the action from frame 3 to frame 3.

You need one action actuator for each position.
[image]

## Option B)

When you want to set position A, assign a property "frame" the value 1 and activate an action actuator in property mode playing the frame of property "frame".

[image]

Comment: Great! option A worked very well for me! Thank you so much!